# Открытие файлов в ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

В папке лежит много разных **xml**, которые необходимо добавить в базу данных. Механизм получения данных из **xml** есть, но работает, если я загружаю файлы через сайт. То есть при добавлении файла в базу данных происходит сравнение названия файла в базе и в папке. Хочу автоматизировать данный процесс через cron. Не могу понять как мне получить список имен файлов и добавить их в базу данных.

Вот контроллер, который загружает файлы через сайт:

```
folder="public/mse/upload/all"
FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{Rails.root}/#{folder}") unless File.directory?("#{Rails.root}/#{folder}")
params[:xml_attachments].each do |uploaded|
    filename = uploaded.original_filename
    unless MseXml.where(xml_id: filename).present?
        File.open(Rails.root.join(folder, uploaded.original_filename),'wb') do |file|
            file.write(uploaded.read)
        end
MseXml.create(xml_id: filename)
```

Из формы берется **params[:xml_attachments]**:

```
 =form_tag load_files_xml_path, method: 'post', multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal" do
    %h3 Выбрать файлы
    =file_field_tag :file, :multiple => true, name: "xml_attachments[]"
    %br
    =submit_tag 'Загрузить файлы', class: "btn btn-primary"
```

**mse_xmls** имеет поле **xml_id**, которое содержит имя файла.

Пример: **000CD110-41B6-407F-A9EF-6A35A5D5D2A7.xml**

Как реализовать получение всех имен файлов и добавление этих имен в MseXml?

Наглядно это выгляди так:

```
names=список имен файла.each do |f|(работа с 1 файлом)
unless MseXml.where(xml_id: f).present?
      MseXml.create(xml_id: f)
      puts 'файл сохранен'
    end
```

Я не могу разбить список файлов по 1 файлу, у меня в базу либо записывается весь массив либо не записывается ничего

Comment: вы хотите взять список имен файлов из какой-то папки и добавить их в базу? и все это делать вне сервера?

Comment: @mikhail-vaysman, файлы загружаются в папку на сервере,затем уже через cron я запускаю rake задание, которое и парсит файлы и забирает все, что необходимо в бд. Меня интересует только как мне правильно получить имена файлов, чтоб я их добавил в mse_xmls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пример, этот код напечатает все имена файлов с расширением **xml** в папке **/tmp**

```
Dir.chdir("/tmp") do
  Dir.glob("*.xml").each do |file_name|
    puts file_name
  end
end
```

Comment: Спасибо вроде то, что нужно. Сейчас оптимизирую под свою задачу.

Answer (score 2):

> Не могу понять как мне получить список имен файлов

Вы можете выполнить `shell` команды и получить список файлов из директории по ответу.

Например:

```
names = `ls path/to/xml_files | grep xml`.split("\n")
```

Получив имена файлов Вы уже можете работать с ними.

Comment: Получая список да, но как мне его разбить по 1 ячейке, если же я использую each то происходит ошибка.

Comment: @an0mality если возникает ошибка, то единственное что могу предложить - посмотреть что у вас хранится в `names`. Может быть команда выполнилась с ошибками.

Comment: И вам спасибо, ответ правильный, но для реализации моей задачки не совсем подошло, но список файлов выводит.